# If $A\times A$ is Borel must $A$ be Borel?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-sets

Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space and $A\subset X$ a subset such that $A\times A$ a Borel subset of $X\times X$.
Is $A$ necessarily Borel?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define $f:X\to X\times X$ by $f(x)=(x,x)$.  Then $f$ is continuous, and $f^{-1}(A\times A)=A$.  If $A\times A$ is Borel, it follows that $A$ is Borel.

Comment: Elegant :) +1 no doubt